# is there a way to have a button persist throughout UINavigationController stack?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I know how to add a button to each controller I push into the navigation controller stack.
But I need to have a settings button on the upper right of the navigation bar, at all times, regardless of which controller gets pushed or popped. The button should present a settings viewController modally.

To me, having each controller's viewDidLoad include code for the button plus including the settings controller header seems like a hack.

Seems like I should be able to insert this button from the navigation controller itself, pointing to a selector in the navigation controller. And this method would then present the settingsController modally through whichever controller happens to be active in the stack at that point.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this is what I did:

**1 - subclass UINavigationController and include the header for my settings controller**

**2 - override** `-pushViewController:aniamted:`

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
    UIBarButtonItem *settingsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Settings" 
                                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                     target:self
                                                                     action:@selector(shouldPresentSettingsView)];
    [viewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem: settingsButton];
    [settingsButton release];
}
```

**3 - add two methods:**

```
- (void)shouldPresentSettingsView
{
    SetupViewController *settingsView = [[SetupViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *tempController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:settingsView];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                    target:self 
                                                                    action:@selector(shouldDismissSettingsView)];
    settingsView.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
    [self.visibleViewController presentModalViewController:tempController animated:YES];

    [cancelButton release];
    [settingsView release];
    [tempController release];
}

- (void)shouldDismissSettingsView
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your navigation controller's delegate to something global, like the app delegate. In that object, initialise a UIBarButtonItem and save to an instance variable:

```
- (void)setupSettingsButton
{
    settingsBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose 
                                                                      target:self 
                                                                      action:@selector(openSettings)];
}
```

Then configure each view controller's navigationItem before it is pushed:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)aNavigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingsBarButton;
}
```

and handle the button action...

```
- (void)openSettings
{
    [navigationController presentViewController:settingsVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your idea. Though, in the meantime I ended coming up with another approach (see my answer) which I feel might be more appropriate from a design point of view, as it keeps the new behavior confined to the navigation controller. But yeah, I mean... concept-wise, I see your point and one could also argue this is a "delegate" task.

Comment: Yeah, I see. I generally prefer delegation and composition over inheritance, but I think in this case we're both on shaky ground design-wise anyway, since we're modifying the navigationItem of the pushed view controller from outside of that view controller code. The most *correct* way might be to have a subclass of UIViewController which always displays this button. But it's splitting hairs at this point anyway. Glad you got it working.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think I've actually heard before that ViewControllers should indeed not modify their own navigation item. The idea I guess is that in a perfect world, the view controller doesn't even know it might exist in the context of a navigation controller. So either the "pusher" (new terminology here... just made up the concept of pusher and pushee :p ) setups of the pushee's navigationItem before pushing it or, better yet (at least in my eyes), not even a the pusher controller should know about configuring the next controller.

Comment: I don't know. At least in the case, I think the solution I came up with makes the most sense design-wise: The different controllers only know about their existence and construction in isolation, regardless of any container. And the navigation controller subclass is a specialization on the navigation controller which adds to how a normal navigation controller modifies the context of the host controllers by providing the whole modal capability. But again, thanks a bunch for your idea.